# Cassandra does not show or apply index when adding secondary index

Tags: nosql, cassandra, thrift, phpcassa

Cassandra seems to have automatically deleted an important secondary index so I have to restore it.

I used both PHPcassa and the Cassandra CLI to restore the index.

Both reported the index was applied, but when I went to try and retrieve the data according to the index, it complains that the indexed column is not there.

This is the latest Cassandra version 1.1.2.

Thanks and help quick!

Comment: Can you provide details on how you're trying to create the index, what query you're using, and what error you're getting?

Comment: Hi Tyler, I used PHPcassa to create the index as highlighted in their documentation http://thobbs.github.com/phpcassa/tutorial.html#indexes. The strangest thing is that I do not get any error, and that the report was the index was created, however when I try to retrieve it, again based on the query in the above documentation, it complains the indexed column is not found.